# non-finite value supplied by optim using Pareto optimization

Tags: r, algorithm, function, optimization

I am trying to follow the instructions from the [`GPareto` R package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=GPareto) to optimize an arbitrary function that I defined.

Here is the function (7 inputs, 4 outputs):

```
library(gpareto)
library(dplyr)

# create some data for this example
a1 = rnorm(1000,100,10)
b1 = rnorm(1000,100,5)
c1 = sample.int(1000, 1000, replace = TRUE)
train_data = data.frame(a1,b1,c1)

funct_set <- function (x) {
    x1 <- x[1]; x2 <- x[2]; x3 <- x[3] ; x4 <- x[4]; x5 <- x[5]; x6 <- x[6]; x[7] <- x[7]
    f <- numeric(4)
   
    #bin data according to random criteria
    train_data <- train_data %>%
        mutate(cat = ifelse(a1 <= x1 & b1 <= x3, "a",
                            ifelse(a1 <= x2 & b1 <= x4, "b", "c")))
    
    train_data$cat = as.factor(train_data$cat)
    
    #new splits
    a_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "a") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    b_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "b") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    c_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "c") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
   
    #calculate  quantile ("quant") for each bin
    
    table_a = data.frame(a_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = ifelse(c1 > x[5],1,0 )))
    table_b = data.frame(b_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = ifelse(c1 > x[6],1,0 )))
    table_c = data.frame(c_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = ifelse(c1 > x[7],1,0 )))
    f[1] = mean(table_a$quant)
    f[2] = mean(table_b$quant)
    f[3] = mean(table_c$quant)
    
    #group all tables
    final_table = rbind(table_a, table_b, table_c)
    # calculate the total mean 
    f[4] = mean(final_table$quant)
   
    return (f)
}
```

I then set up the specifications for the optimization (e.g. upper and lower bounds, number of iterations):

```
lower=c(80,80,80,80, 100,200,300)
upper=c(120,120,120,120,200,300,400)
budget <- 25
```

Next, I run the optimization algorithm:

```
omEGO <- easyGParetoptim(fn = funct_set, budget = budget, lower = lower, upper = upper)
```

But this produces an error:

> Error in optim(par = parinit, fn = fn, gr = gr, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = lower,  :  non-finite value supplied by optim

I tried to look at other posts on Stack Overflow that encountered similar errors: ["non-finite value supplied by optim" error when using betareg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51504407/non-finite-value-supplied-by-optim-error-when-using-betareg)

But I am not sure how to apply the logic from these posts to fix my problem.

Comment: put some `print()` or `cat()` statements in your function that print out the current values of the parameters and the return value; that way you can identify where the problem is occurring

Comment: @Ben Bolker: Thank you for your reply! I added "print()" to the end function (func_set) and got the following error: Error in print.default() : argument "x" is missing, with no default

Comment: I added "cat()" to the end of the function (func set) and got the following error: Error in optim(par = parinit, fn = fn, gr = gr, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = lower,  : 
  non-finite value supplied by optim

Comment: Is this what you meant? Thank you for all your help!

Comment: You need to `print()` or `cat()` **something**, i.e. you need to specify some arguments (e.g. your parameter values and objective function values)

Comment: thank you for your suggestions - I am still working on this. I feel lost - can you please take a look at this is if you have some time?

Answer (score 3):

Partial solution, which should at least get you started with debugging.

1. I inserted the following lines:

```r
print(x)
print(f)
```

before the `return(f)` statement.

It illustrates lots of places where one of  your sub-functions returns `NaN`, e.g. on the very first line:

```
      x.1       x.2       x.3       x.4       x.5       x.6       x.7 
 91.55028 117.93290  87.38835  99.87770 100.53399 260.07302 310.29938 
[1]       NaN 0.7160494 0.7023346 0.7090000
```

(the first line represents the arguments, the second the values of the sub-functions).

2. I then ran

```r
debug(funct_set)
x1 <- c(91.55028,117.93290,87.38835,99.87770,100.53399,260.07302,310.29938)
funct_set(x1)
```

i.e., setting the initial values that were passed to the function and stepping through the code to see what happens (where the `NaN` comes from).

3. Running `table(train_data$cat)` interactively after the binning step, we get

```
  b   c 
486 514
```

that is, there are *no values in your training data set that satisfy the condition* `a1 <= x1 & b1 <= x3`.

Therefore, the derived table `a_table` is empty (zero rows); `table_a`, derived from it, is also empty; `table_a$quant` is a length-zero vector; and `mean(table_a$quant)` is `NaN` (the mean of a zero-length vector is undefined, as `sum(x)/length(x)` is 0/0).

If empty bins are a reasonable outcome, then you need to decide what objective function value should be returned (it could be something as simple as `if (nrow(table_a)==0) 0 else mean(table_a$quant)`, if zero would be a reasonable return value). Otherwise you need to figure out how to constrain your parameters so this doesn't happen.